# Eliminar reportes repetidos por día de una persona

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqldb

Estoy tratando de eliminar los reportes que haya hecho una persona el mismo día, que solo me quede un registro por día, pero lo único que me da es el `SELECT`, cuando le coloco el `DELETE` no me funciona, lo estoy haciendo con MySQL Workbench.

```sql
DELETE FROM registro_empleado
WHERE FechaIngreso IN (
    SELECT FechaIngreso FROM registro_empleado
    GROUP BY dayofweek(FechaIngreso), NumCedula HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
    order by FechaIngreso ASC
);
```

Este es el código que estoy implementando.

¿Alguno sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no me quiere dar"? ¿Da un error? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta, y no olvides darle formato a la consulta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: La estructura es un poco confusa., además de no tener formato de código. En un sitio utilizas `dayofweek` y en otro no, etc. Pero en cualquier caso... corrigiendo eso, con esa sentencia borrarías todos los registros que tengan más de un reporte por fecha. Así que cuidado, porque borrarías también el que no quieres

Comment: Muchas gracias, como era mi primera pregunta no sabia como formularla, pero gracias por la información, lo tendré en cuenta para una próxima ocasión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Tu tabla tiene un id?. Suponiendo que si, y teniendo la siguiente data de prueba:

```
id | FechaIngreso | NumCedula
---+--------------+-------
1  | 2022-05-13   | ced01
2  | 2022-05-13   | ced01
3  | 2022-06-01   | ced02
4  | 2022-06-08   | ced03
5  | 2022-06-08   | ced03
```

Si quisieras consultar el registro único con el **id mínimo** en la tabla:

```sql
SELECT MIN(id) FROM registro_empleado 
GROUP BY FechaIngreso, NumCedula
```

Esto da:

```
MIN(id)
-------
1
3
4
```

Entonces, con la consulta anterior se puede armar otra consulta para eliminar todos los demás registros:

```sql
DELETE FROM registro_empleado 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT MIN(id) FROM registro_empleado 
        GROUP BY FechaIngreso, NumCedula
    ) Temp
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias con esa consulta pude eliminar los registros que no necesitaba, lo único que tuve que agregarle es en el GROUP BY el DAYOFWEEK para que me eliminara los registros por día

Comment: Si @CamiloBohorquez lo del DAYOFWEEK se me pasó, pero el concepto era lo importante ;) . Si te sirvió, puedes marcar la respuesta como Aceptada. Saludos.